# Adding multiple products in many2many field in custom module should convert into invoice lines

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I am adding multiple products in my field.Now I have two convert those product list one by one into invoice lines automatically.I create a button when i will click on that it will create a invoice automatically.But not able to add the invoice lines of the product.

Can anyone help me how to add the many products to the invoice lines one by one.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call create method with a dicionary of the values with the the id of the current poduct:

```
@api.one
def _add_to_invoice(self):
   #you need to pass the the id of the product to the invoice and add others  
   #fields too
   self.env['invoice'].create({'product_id',int(self.id),'field_one':your_value})
```